# React function component not rendering after this && even though it is a valid string

Tags: reactjs

So This isn't rendering Hello World even though Reward is set to a string.

```
 {console.log(reward, "<<Reward")}
    {reward && (
      <div>
        Hello World
      </div>
    )}
```

So it is actually rendering the first time around. Then after I setReward (to a valid value) it doesn't actually render Hello World.

This is really bizarre and I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: can you share more code? I'm unable to identify a problem with the given snippet. Is it possible `reward` is an empty string?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted. https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cherry-hfzksw?file=/src/App.js. You would get a better answer if you [edit] your question and provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem happening.